# Extracting files from stream-mode tarfile

Tags: python, stream, tar

I`ve got an stream which contains .tar file conten, so I work with it using tarfile.open('r|')
What I need to do - is to look into list of files inside it and read some of them, then upload whole tar into another place.

When I try to tarfile.extractfile() after tarfile.getnames() it raises an tarfile.StreamError. But I cannot extract file which name I dont know.

How can I get list of files without crushing tarfile? I cannot save the whole tar into RAM\disk, because some files inside it can be larger than 10GB.

```
>>> tf = tarfile.open(fileobj=open('Downloads/clean-alpine.ova', 'rb'), mode='r|')
>>> tfn = tf.getnames()
>>> tfn
['clean-alpine.ovf', 'clean-alpine.mf', 'clean-alpine-disk1.vmdk']
>>> tf.fileobj
<tarfile._Stream object at 0x7ff878dac7b8>
>>> tf.fileobj.pos
33595392
>>> ovf = tf.extractfile('clean-alpine.ovf')
>>> ovf
<ExFileObject name=''>
>>> d = ovf.read().decode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 696, in read
    self.fileobj.seek(offset + (self.position - start))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 522, in seek
    raise StreamError("seeking backwards is not allowed")
tarfile.StreamError: seeking backwards is not allowed
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of [`TarFile.extractall()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9194a20a5b0b933a2a43ce0e81becbf8f0356314/Lib/tarfile.py#L1981-L2019) the important bit is to use `TarFile` as an iterable, like I did in my use case:

```
for member in tf:
    if not member.isfile():
        continue
    dest = Path.cwd() / member.name  # This is vulnerable to, like, 5 things
    with tf.extractfile(member) as tfobj:
        dest.write_bytes(tfobj.read())
```

Comment: The important line here is the first one in the code snippet. The OP uses `tf.getnames()`, which may be accessing the stream in a way later operations cannot work anymore (stream not seek-able). Using the iterator suggested by @AstraLuma works.